# <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require':

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

I am working on the learn.co Web Development Fundamentals track. When I try to run on terminal a ruby file

```
ruby looping.rb
```

I get the following error:

```
<internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `require': cannot load such file -- rubygems.rb (LoadError)
from <internal:gem_prelude>:1:in `<compiled>'
```

This wasnt happening before, I had to reinstall the Learn Environment Setup, but now is not working.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this problem by doing the following:

```
rvm fix-permissions
```

and then:

```
rvm reinstall 2.2.3
```